# Pure CSS Dropdown Menu Problems

Tags: html, css

I'm using the pure CSS menu shown [here](http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/).

Works fine and all, but I want to put the created menu into another div region to make a bar across the page.

This only works if I put an overflow in this section:

```
#nav{
    list-style:none;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    margin-left:30%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

This then stops the drop down bar working.

Any idea how I can get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be able to omit the `overflow:auto/hidden;` you have several options:

use a fixed height on `#nav` (or on the div) to expand it to the same height of its children (potentially critical: if you not working with fixed heights on the children `li`s, you may not know their exact height (=calculate it via font-size, line-height and boxmodell))

or

use `clear:left;` on the `#nav`, either with help of the `:after` pseudo-element (beware ie<=7!) or with an extra element in the surrounding div [(described here)](http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html).

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <ul id="nav">
    <li></li>
    ....
 </ul>
 <div style="clear:left;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you'd like to achieve and why do you need to use overflow for this example? Could you just modify t[his example](http://jsfiddle.net/adaz/Xtbsp/)?

If it's just to clear floats, you can use [clearfix](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) (ie6+).

Comment: his questions is a bit confusing, but i had the same problem some time ago. If you want to have a "bar", say with some bg-color, then you need to clear the floats or use overflow hidden or use a fixed height on the parent element, otherwise it will collapse and have 0 height.

Answer (score -1):

I would try this:

Change:

```
  overflow: auto;
```

to:

```
  overflow: visible;
```

Or, if you like this look better, with a scrollbar,

Change:

```
  overflow: auto;
```

To:

```
   overflow: scroll;
```

Either of those two options will help the client view whatever text is missing.  It's just up to the way you want it to look, and how much space you're working with.  But either of those two options are viable.  Hope this helps.

Comment: There's a chance I misunderstood the question, but I don't have to test it; I use it.  They have the same things on css-tricks.com.

Comment: No reason to downvote me. If you had tested this, you would have noticed, that this wont't work...

Comment: But I'm always willing to learn, can you please provide the link to the article you are referring?